# Does every solidity contract need to be migrated individually in truffle?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have a .sol file with an ERC20 token and 3 "contracts" (The token interface, safemath and TestToken). In my migrations folder, do I need to do a separate migration file for each of the contracts? Or is a truffle migration done per .sol file for all of the contracts collectively?

TestToken.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Safe Math Library 
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract SafeMath {

    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }

    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a); 
        c = a - b; 
    } 

    function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { 
        c = a * b; 
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b); 
    } 

    function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { 
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}


contract TestToken is ERC20Interface, SafeMath {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals; // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    
    uint256 public _totalSupply;
    
    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;
    
    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    constructor() public {
        name = "TestToken";
        symbol = "TEST";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 100000000;
        
        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }
    
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }
    
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
}
```

2_deploy_migration.js

```
const TestToken = artifacts.require("TestToken");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TestToken);
};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your contract TestToken inherits from ERC20Interface and SafeMath so you only need to deploy this one, as you did in your migration script.